# 6 coins' box, an expected value of the number of tosses which heads was tossed.

Tags: probability, expected-value

In a box there are 6 coins, three ordinary coins, two with heads on both sides and one with tails on both sides. A coin is selected randomly from the box and is tossed 100 times.

1. What is the expectation value of the number of tosses of heads?
2. What is the expectation value of the number of tosses of heads, if it's given that in the first toss we got heads?

As for 1. I am not so sure but the expectation value of one toss of heads is: $3\times (1/2)+2\times 1$, so in our case the expectation value should be $(\frac{7}{2})^{100}$, am I correct?

As for 2. I think you should replace 100 with 99, am I correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should attack these with conditional expectation in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, what is the probability of $H$ in a flip? There are three possibilities for choosing a coin - ordinary coin (coin $1$), coin with both sides as Heads (coin $2$), coin with both sides as tail (coin $3$).

$ \small P(H) = P(H \mid 1) \cdot P(1) + P(H \mid 2) \cdot P(2) + P(H \mid 3) \cdot P(3)$

$ \small \displaystyle P(H) = \frac 12 \cdot \frac 36 + 1 \cdot \frac 26 + 0 = \frac 7{12}$

So, $ \small  \displaystyle E[X] = 100 \cdot P(H) = \frac{175}{3}$

For the second question, find the conditional probability of choosing coin $1$, $2$ and $3$ *given* first toss showed $H$. For example,

$ \small \displaystyle P(1 \mid H) = \frac{P(H \mid  1) \cdot P(1)}{P(H)} = \frac{(1/2) \cdot (3/6)}{7/12} = \frac 37$

Now use the approach in the first question to find expected number of $H$ in $100$ flips.

Comment: Also for the second question, be careful when calculating $E[X]$ as the first toss is already given as $H$.

Comment: So it should be 99 instead of 100.

Comment: Yes when you find the revised probability of $H$ in a toss given the first toss is $H$, that is applicable for $99$ flips so multiply by $99$. Then add $1$ to it as  the first flip is $H$. I hope that clarifies. Also, once you complete, you can comment here to validate the answer.

Comment: I get $P(H|H)=P(1|H)P(H|1)P(1)+P(2|H)P(H|2)P(2)=\frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{7}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{4}{7}=25/84$. So $E(X|H)=99\cdot \frac{25}{84}+1$. Am I correct here? Thanks.

Comment: No that is not correct. The conditional probability of picking coin $1$ is $3/7$ and $P(H \mid 1) = 1/2$. So $P(H \mid H \text{ in first toss}) = \frac37 \cdot \frac12 + \frac 47 \cdot 1 = \frac {11}{14}$. Then $E[X \mid H] = 99 \cdot \frac {11}{14} + 1$